# MongoDB - Cannot $merge to internal database: admin

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm executing a .Js script on unix that execute several aggregation pipelines, extracting and merging data on a MongoDB Collections.

I've tested it on a MongoDB instance (v7.0) I've installed and run as expected withotu error and extracting all the expected data.

I've launched the same script on another MongoDB Cluster (v6.0), set in replica mode and managed by ops tool manager, but the script doesn't complete and I get the error "Cannot $merge to internal database: admin".
I've noted that on this cluster, the script always fail with that error, but on different pipelines at random.

Unfortunately, I can not uploda here the aggregation pipeline, but the only stage with merge is like this:

```
{
        $merge: {
          into: "AGGREGATE_COLLECTION",
          on: "_id",
          whenMatched: "replace",
          whenNotMatched: "insert",
        },
      }
```

At the end of the aggregation pipeline, and the aggregation is executed with the simple command:

```
var newdb= db.getSiblingDB(dynamicDatabase);
    newdb.COLLECTION.aggregate([
```

Since the same script is working fine on my MongoDB istance and on the replica one fails at different stages randomly, I think it may depend on some configuration of the cluster but have no idea.
Is there something I could check for?

Update:
I've noted another weird behaviour. This error only happens when I launch it from the unix shell, while it's completed with success when launched by the crontab scheduled, even using the same unix user.

Comment: Mostlikely `newdb` in your above code is `Admin`

Comment: No, I print before the database and it's one that is expected, with a concatanation like this      var dynamicDatabase= 'PREFIX_'+String.replace("/", "_");
.

Comment: You might enable auditing, or increase the log verbosity of the server to get more detail about what exactly is being submitted to the server.